# T-SQL Date Display

Tags: t-sql, function, date

I have a table where I select customer purchase activity and it will display the date of purchase (along with the time) in `ColumnA`, in this format:

```
2012-08-06 10:06:42.223
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

I want to display the date only, so I added a LEFT function like so:

```
LEFT(ColumnA, 11)
```

This will get rid of the time but now the date is displayed I will get:

```
Aug  06 2012
```

I want to display it in numeric format but as `MM/DD/YYYY` so it will look like:

```
08/06/2012
MM/DD/YYYY
```

Any ideas how I can do this in T-SQL?

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to convert it:

```
SELECT convert(char(10), getdate(), 101)
```

or from your table:

```
SELECT convert(char(10), yourDate, 101)
FROM yourTable
```

Here is a handy website with the conversions:

[How to format datetime & date in Sql Server 2005](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

Or if you just want yourDate value without the time, you can always use which results in `2012-08-06 00:00:00.000`:

```
declare @yourDate datetime
set @yourdate = '2012-08-06 10:06:42.223'

select DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, @yourdate), 0)
```

Or from yourTable:

```
select DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, yourDateField), 0)
from yourTable
```

Comment: Can I do this dynamically with a variable so I don't have to specify the specific date with a set @yourdate = '2012-08-06' ?

Comment: @FredStevaans see my edit, you would just replace your date field with your column.  I was just showing that as an example

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ColumnA, 101)
FROM MyTable
```